# Repeat markings

Tags: notation, engraving, repeats

When a portion of music, say 16 bars from the start, has a repeat sign at the end of that 16th bar, the direction means go back and start again. The sign I mean is **I**I: at the beginning. So why do some pieces have a reverse repeat sign *at* the beginning. There's nowhere else to go back to, it seems pointless. Why is it featured in some music?

Comment: Any image example of notation? If the piece starts with a "|:", then I would say that the typesetter just wanted to "close their parentheses". If it starts with a ":|", well then it's something weird and I haven't ever seen that. (I haven't seen either, in fact.)

Comment: I haven't seen this as well, and would like to see an example, if you have one.

Comment: I'm thinking I've seen this in vocal parts for congregational singing where the instrumental introduction is omitted. But I don't think it has any significance anywhere it might appear.

Comment: Check today's question: 'Functional harmony'. By reverse, I mean two lines followed with two dots.

Comment: @Tim this is in the same category as "why mark naturals in the measure after an  accidental" -- it's done to make the music easier to read and reduce any question of typos in the published part.  Consider it a musical equivalent of a  CRC or   FEC  (terms from digital communication theory)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - not a clue about CRC or FEC - too much jargon. So, you think the answer is 'courtesy repeat marks'? Could be an answer? And typos? Shouldn't be there anyway! How would a typo portray itself as a repeat sign and cause confusion? Not convinced.

Comment: @Tim  yes,the short answer is "courtesy repeat" .   As to jargon,  defining them  won't make sense unless you're sufficiently curious to run off and learn about error-handling in digital transmissions,  Shannon Theory, and all sort of other techno nerd stuff :-)

Comment: In addition to the existing answers essentially saying: "It's easier for the musician", are you looking for an origin story of the practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about something like this? This is a excerpt from “The Latin Real Book” by Sher Publishing.

[image]

I learned a backward repeat goes back to the top if there is no forward repeat and I agree it is not necessary but then again I have seen dozens of published pieces and professionally copied charts written with and without the starting repeat at the top. I’m guessing someone decided to do it x years ago, maybe for the sake of clarity and it caught on.

It doesn’t bother me personally because if I’m sight reading I start with the knowledge that I will be returning to the top of the piece.

Comment: That's the point. Why bother? It's a sort of musical tautology.

Comment: @Tim So is this a question with a pinch of complaint?

Comment: It's a question which asks why do the unnecessary. In life, don't we try to improve, streamline, make more efficient?

Comment: So basically, it's there to tell readers that sooner or later, there will be a repeat sign. It's not particularly there to say where to go back to.

Comment: This example comes from a realbook. The score is likely to be read a vista so this extra hint may help the musician to get it right first time.

Comment: Accepted answer based on last para. It's more than a courtesy, it's a warning!

Comment: WARNING! Failure to execute this repeat will result in fines and possible incarceration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when a repeat goes back to the beginning, a Start Repeat barline is not required.   But neither is it prohibited.  And you'll often see one.

There's no logical 'why'.  Not like the 'why for a cautionary accidental.  People do it.  It does no harm.  Be like Elsa and Let It Go.

Comment: I do often see one. The question is why? Just another piece of superfluous information.

Comment: @Tim - I think John Belzaguy's answer has why: while redundant, the starting repeat sign *unambiguously* declares that the beginning music will be repeated at some point.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - that actually, is probably the real reason for it - to warn that there will be a repeat sign soonish. But, in reality, it's still pointless, imo.

Comment: There's no logical 'why'.  Not like the 'why for a cautionary accidental.

Comment: See Carl's comment - he would disagree.

Comment: @Tim   again,  the best way to ensure error-free operation is in fact to allow for some redundancy or "superfluousness."  Don't make things difficult for the user in the name of some peri-OCD reasoning.   It's like saying there shouldn't be keyboard shortcuts for menu items 3 layers deep .

Answer (score 1):

It might just be for consistency, because that is how one would usually enclose repeats. Also, it doesn’t hurt to make things unambiguous, even though it’s not really necessary, sort of like a courtesy accidental, perhaps.

Also, sometimes there is an anacrusis right before the reverse repeat sign, in which case you would not repeat the anacrusis; but I don’t think this is what you were talking about.

Edit: I don't know much about the use of courtesy/cautionary accidentals, so maybe I shouldn't have made that comparison. Anyways, the point I was trying to make was that being unambiguous doesn't hurt.

Comment: With an anarucis, there would be a necessity for the 'reverse repeat' (as I call it).

Comment: @Tim Yes, I agree.